# Is it possible to reassign const variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

Is it possible in JavaScript to reassign const variable;
In C++ we can cast variable to and from const, but is it something similar possible in JavaScript;

Here I ask about

```
const a = 1;
unconst(a);
a = "xyz";
a === "xyz" // true
```

Not object properties reassignments and array push/pop; 
or

```
let a = 1;
const(a);
a = "xyz"; // error 
a === 1 // true
```

a is const now, something like Object.freeze for objects

Comment: Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared. - quoted from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: `const` has a different meaning in C than it does in Javascript, they aren't exactly the same thing.

Comment: I understand it different, but is there any workaround to const and unconst them?

Answer (score 1):

No, not with standard API. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared.
>
> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable—just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its properties) can be altered.